# Laravel / Host Setup for Multi-TLD

Tags: laravel, routes, hosting, multiple-domains, tld

Basically Ive written out this about 5 times, still dont know how to properly ask, so here goes...

I want two domains, say **example.net** and **example.info** which I have registered. I want them to point to the one application I'm building, then hopefully use Laravel to route the two different domains to there own pages... here is what I've tried and what problems I've ran into...

** #1 Domain Forward **

Uploaded my app to example.net and forwarded the .info domain to the .net domain. And then tried...

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.info'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){ return 'INFO PAGE!'; });
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.net'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){ return 'NET PAGE!'; });
});

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

**Problems**

1. Laravel Domain Routing doesnt seem to recognise domains without subdomains, eg '{subdomain}.example.net' will work, but 'example.net' and 'example.info' wont?
2. When domain forwarding, the `HTTP_HOST` will always show **.net** and not **.info**, so cant use `if` or `switch` statement in the routes file

**Alternative Soloution**

The only soloution i can think of is to use my host's shared hosting setup to have two individual sites, each with the appropriate domains pointing to them and set my IDE to upload to both sites?

Surely there is a better way to do this tho?

Any help would be great, also Im pretty new to this so if you could keep it simple please, thanks... jimmy

Comment: This isn't what Laravel is for.  Look into virtual hosts.

Comment: I understand how to set up virtual hosts for development, I want to know what the best way to set up one application across multiple domains?

Comment: Put the same application in different vhosts each vhost has a different domain..?

Comment: Yeah but how do I do that on the live server?

Comment: Reread my last comment...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies guys, this is what i ended up doing... just putting the routes into variable and passing it to route groups, seems to work for me

```
$frontendRoutes = function()
{
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return 'Index Page';
    })
};

Route::group(['domain' => 'example.net'], $frontendRoutes);
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.info'], $frontendRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but the php artisan routes looks a bit wrong.

http://ryantablada.com/post/multi-tld-routing-in-laravel

I was having a problem having the code pick up the last tld in the list.  This, although not perfect, seems to be the best answer I have found so far.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a crazy hack, but as I ended up with the same issue and I wanted to have two tld's pointing to my site and then serve a different language depending on what tld they were coming from I made this solution.

I created a folder called Routes in the app folder.

I then added two folders in the the Routes folder, one named "com" and one named "se".

And in each folder I added the files I wanted to use depending on what language.
in the "com" folder I made a file called  pages.php with the code:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('about', [
    'as' => 'about',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@about'
]);
```

And then I added a file in the "se" folder also named pages.php with the code:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('om-oss', [
    'as' => 'about',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@about'
]);
```

Then back at the routes.php I added this code:

```
$tld = strrchr ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "." );
$tld = substr ( $tld, 1 );

foreach (File::allFiles(__DIR__.'\Routes\/'.$tld) as $partial) 
{
require_once $partial->getPathname();
}
```

So now I have one folder for each tld, not the best solution but it works.