# have same base code for multiple TLDs

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, routes, multiple-domains, tld

For example:

**abc.com**

There's a *registration/login* authentication build in *Codeigniter* using *REST API*

**somename.bm**

Again there's a *registration/login* authentication build in *Laravel* using same ^ *REST API*

Both these domains uses same concept of authentication of the user and even after login, most of the pages are same (expect for the data we choose to display and css).

**Now my simple question is**, is there any way where I can have a common code where both these websites access the same controller and somehow I differentiate the call and then simply call the REST API to access the data and display accordingly.

Again, if I miss something or need further elaboration, feel free to contact me here.

Comment: You can have the same controller and model for each website but change the view folder called in config/view.php .

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the feedback, I will try it out. I also came across this page, what do you think?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349978/laravel-host-setup-for-multi-tld

Comment: The answer from Jimmy in the other thread can work but you will have to duplicate every route.

Comment: @Roadirsh - I will still need to have an installation of Laravel per domain? So how can I "have the same controller and model for each website but change the view folder called in config/view.php"?

From other threads I understand that I have to make some changes in routes.php as well (if needed) but If I have installation of Laravel at 2 different places... How will the code take affect?

Again, I apologize for asking basic questions. (just started working on this project few days back)

Comment: no, you will have one folder on an apache server like any other domain. But for the second tld you will have to point to the same server and in your view.php you will have to make a condition based on the tld to check which view folder you should use.