# Laravel keeps logging me out after login

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel set up. I am running multiple domains to it. Before yesterday I had one top level domain and a few sub domains. I added another TLD yesterday and everything started working weird. Specifically, when trying to log into the admin section it redirects to the home page. I have one admin but server domains coming to the site. My route group it:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
```

Sometimes is actually brings me into the admin but as soon as I click on a link I get logged out and redirected to the home page. I keep seeing 401 errors in the console as well.

What would cause this?

edit

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
        Route::get('/pages', 'AdminController@pages');
        Route::get('page/create', 'AdminController@createPagePage');
        Route::post('createPage', 'AdminController@createPage');
        Route::get('/page/edit/{page_id}', 'AdminController@editPagePage');
        Route::post('editPage', 'AdminController@editPage');
});

$redirectTo = '/';
```

Comment: Are u using laravel default auth system?

Comment: Yes, I have not changed that

Comment: Have you checked the log for anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Yes, nothing so far

Comment: Please edit your question and post the routes that compose the route group, and the value of `$redirectTo` variable, at `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController` file.

Comment: done, there are a few more routes in there but they are all basically the same

Comment: Try disabled the auth working perfectly for all the pages?

Comment: Last night I logged in through the original domain and it works fine. No issues. It’s only when I log in under the new domain that I get logged out.

Comment: Do you have `Auth::logout()` somewhere on your view?

Comment: No, I did a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, try to check the session file permissions and change them so the app can write session keys on that file and if it doesn't work, try to change the session driver to **database**.

*how to change the session driver?*

1. Go to your .env file and change SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database.
2. create a session migration: php artisan session:table.
3. composer dump-autoload.
4. Finally migrate (php artisan migrate).

Comment: Hi @Djellal this seemed to work. I made the change yesterday and so far so good. Was this because the load balancer saved the sessions on different servers but all the sites share a db?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setting the SESSION_DOMAIN right?

> One thing you may notice is that session isn’t saved when the user is logged-in in one store and goes to another. To fix that issue, we’ll need to add a SESSION_DOMAIN variable to our .env file, for example:
>
> SESSION_DOMAIN=’.example.com’
>
> That’s all, now user session will be shared across all shops/subdomains in our app.

https://medium.com/@maxkostinevich/how-to-build-multi-domain-laravel-application-e6d87d5e507b

Comment: Hi Joshra, I had read this article and tried a few different things but it didnt work. Thanks though

Comment: looks like this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349978/laravel-host-setup-for-multi-tld

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident with the domain setup correctly. Please verify these few things.

**1.** Your `config/session.php` is correctly setup to support multiple domains.

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),  // check /storage folder writtable recursivelly.

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),  // verify if single domain is not given in .env or in settings.

'same_site' => null // it should not be strict if you have ajax request across these domain. I mean from javascript you may try to request to other domain.

etc...
```

**2.** Confirm, if your routes are not group under `domain` specific. something like:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'xxx'], function($params)
{
    // your routes..
});
```

**3.** If there is any hardcoded domain verification/conditions or redirection added in code.

**4.** Any values in .env poiting to single domain.

**5.** Also don't forgot to clear the cache/compiled view/routes and delete the temp files once. like generated files inside `/app/bootstrap` & `/storage`

```
// Clear Application Cache
php artisan cache:clear

// Clear route cache
php artisan route:cache

// Clear config cache
php artisan config:cache  


// Clear compiled view files
php artisan view:clear
```

**6.** Any thirdparty package might contains the domain settings. Make sure to verify the files in your `/config` folder.

**7.** Check the `url rewrite` settings in `.htaccess`

**8.** Do confirm if there is any proxy settings are there or any software installed on server - very rare case.

In case still having issue, please restart the `apache/nginx` service once because sometimes the config changes not effected after change that might need server restart.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Also I'm not sure how you are using this `$redirectTo = '/'`